# How to perform a heavy and long process in cron jobs?

Tags: plugin-development, database, wp-cron

I have a table in my database that has more than 1000 records and new records can add anytime. I run a process on every record of this table daily. I use an event scheduler to do so in WordPress. But as you might know, The runtime of background processes is limited and I think I should break this into multiple processes. 
Yet I want to know that if I should break the big process, what is the best way to do it? Or do you suggest another way to handle this walker on every record?